# NPM/Node not binding to port... (I believe)

Tags: node.js, npm

**I seriously have a big issue with this one guys...**

I am working with StackEdit and it's code. What I am doing with it I shall not waste your time on.
Using gulp I am able to start the project easily, and build it as the original developers intended. However I am failing to build it and when I am running it via

```
npm start
```

I get the same response consistently every time. I run the command that the developers recommend using that binds the application to port 80 and then starts the node javascript application on the port. To me it seems as if its not binding to port or the port is taken by something. I have yet to try a port-avalablity check but I don't think it is nessesary considering that I can get Express applications to bind to the port 3000 (witch I have tried, by the way) appropriatley.

The command I am executing is:

```
(set PORT=80 && node server.js)
```

The following output is copied directly from the console.

```
Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at cb (net.js:1296:16)
    at shared (cluster.js:602:5)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (cluster.js:576:9)
    at process.<anonymous> (cluster.js:737:8)
    at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at handleMessage (internal/child_process.js:695:10)
    at internal/child_process.js:497:7
 Worker died. Spawning a new process...
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
```

It continues to repeat this cycle, printing this on a loop until I CTRL+C and terminate the job.
Again, this seems to me as if its not binding to the port correctly. Using a windows computer. If someone could help, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try executing `set PORT=80` separately instead of on the same line? If that doesn't work, you should post the relevant code from your Express app where you listen on whatever port.

Comment: Don't you already have an apache or nginx running in the background (on port 80) ? + Usually, you start a node app on a random port (like 3000 or 9000) and use nginx (or something else) to reverse proxy to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! It turns out this was my fault. Because I am more farmilliar with bash I installed it and was using it in place of windows command prompt. This is where it failed. Hard. It ceased to operate properly. So I opened it up using the following process:

The windows key and R. Typed the command "cmd" and entered the command in the command prompt

```
set PORT=80 && set DEBUG=stackedit:* && node server.js
```

after, of course I had CD'd into the appropriate directory.